# XSS and URL-encoding

Tags: php, security, xss

1. I enter in the browser: `example.com/139189/john-doe?asf"><script>alert(2)</script>das=23`
2. In template I have this: `<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo 'example.com' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>` (On one place I have similar line, but: ... `urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`)
3. On page source it looks like this, (i.e. browser is performing URL-encoding): `<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/139189/john-doe?asf%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(2)%3C/script%3Edas=23"/>`

The question is: how can someone perform XSS attack in this case? I read on the Net that I should also use htmspecialchars(). Does it, in this case, XSS attack depend on browser?

Also, I read https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules_Summary and it seems to me that my case is in third row of the table.

Comment: Check: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84276/xss-via-request-uri

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a XSS attack on this, or if this is susceptible to XSS attack and how to prevent it?

Comment: @DanMiller I have already seen that, but want to double-check.

Comment: @Barmar I want to know if this is susceptible to XSS attack, how can someone perform it and if it is URL-encoding (by browser and/or PHP) enough for protection (in this case).